# What is the domain and codomain of Fourier inverse transform $\mathcal F^{-1}$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ is defined by
$$Ff(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\xi t}dt$$

Generally, the domain of $\mathcal F$ is $L^1$ since otherwise the integral isn't defined, and the codomain of $\mathcal F$ is $C_0$, which is possible by Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

On the other hand, Fourier inverse transform $\mathcal F^{-1}$ is defined by $$\mathcal F^{-1}f(t)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi)e^{i\xi t}d\xi$$
(Note that $\mathcal F^{-1}$ doesn't mean the inverse mapping of $\mathcal F$.)

I'm wondering what the domain and codomain of Fourier inverse transform is. I searched but I do not find.

Maybe, similarily to Fourier transform, the domain of $\mathcal F^{-1}$ is $L^1$ since otherwise the integral isn't defined. (right?)

And, generally, what is the codomain of Fourier inverse transform ?

Comment: This is complicated because $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(f)=f$ doesn't seem to be true for generic $f\in L^1$

Comment: Yes. $\mathcal F^{-1}$ doesn't mean the inverse mapping of $\mathcal F$, and $\mathcal F^{-1}\mathcal F(f)=f$ doesn't necessarily hold. @FShrike

Comment: As a distribution, the domain and codomain of the Fourier Transform and the Inverse Fourier Transform are the same, the space of Schwartz functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't quite well-formed because there are many valid choices of domain for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$. It depends on what specifically you're trying to do.

As you have observed, the integral formulas for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ are well-defined for $L^1$ functions, but not necessarily so for other functions. With domain $L^1$, both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ have codomains $C_0$, the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. Of course, this means that these are not true inverses of each other in this context.

But it is also possible to define $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ on other domains. For example, $\mathcal{F}$ can be extended to $L^2$ via continuous approximation from the dense subspace $L^1\cap L^2$. In this case $\mathcal{F}$ is no longer defined solely through the integral formula; instead it is defined as a limit. Under this definition, $\mathcal{F}$ can be defined as a map $L^2\to L^2$, and one can also show that an analogous definition of $\mathcal{F}^{-1}:L^2\to L^2$ serves as its inverse.

One can also work on a smaller space, such as the space of Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}$. In that case it is easy to show that the integral definition of $\mathcal{F}$ is an automorphism of Schwartz space and the integral definition of $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is its inverse. One can then generalize this to extend $\mathcal{F}$ to to the space $\mathcal{S}'$ of tempered distributions, which is a much larger space than $L^1$. This turns out to be an isomorphism as well, with inverse $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ (also suitably extended to a map $\mathcal{S}'\to\mathcal{S}'$.

Comment: "Easy"? If an easy proof of the Fourier inversion theorem exists I'd love to see it

Comment: @FShrike Here is one where $f\in \mathbb{S}$.$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\,dk&=\frac1{2\pi}\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-L}^L e^{-ikx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')\int_{-L}^L e^{ik(x'-x)}e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx'\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')\frac{2\sin(L(x'-x))}{x'-x}\,dx'\\\\
&=\frac1{\pi}\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+x'/L)\frac{\sin(x')}{x'}\,dx'\\\\
&=f(x)
\end{align}$$The DCT justifies the last step.

Comment: In addition, the Fourier transform can be defined on a set of functions or on a set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @MarkViola That's quite nice. The proof only needs $f\in L^1$, $f$ continuous at $x$ and that the very first integral is well defined. That was a lot simpler (to me) than the proof presented on Wikipedia!

Comment: @FShrike If $f\in L^1$, then clearly the inner integral (i.e., the FT of $f$ exists). Fubini-Tonelli applies when $f\in L^1$ for the outer integral $\int_{-L}^L$.  But we need something stronger than $f\in L^1$ alone to apply the DCT.

Comment: @MarkViola Ah, though the sinc function is bounded I did not appreciate the subtlety that $f(x+x'/L)$ might not be dominated, I can't just dominate it with itself. That said the conclusion is true so long as $f\in L^1$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ and $\mathcal{F}f\in L^1$, so there should be a way to make your proof idea work on those assumptions

Comment: For $f\in C^1_C$, integrating by parts with $u=f(x')$ and $v=\int_{-\infty}^{x'}\frac{\sin(L(x''-x)}{x''-x}\,dx''$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') \frac{\sin(L(x'-x))}{x'-x}\,dx'&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x') \int_{-\infty}^{x'}\frac{\sin(L(x''-x))}{x''-x}\,dx''\,dx'\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x') \int_{-\infty}^{L(x'-x)}\frac{\sin(x'')}{x'}\,dx''\,dx'\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now we can apply the DCT since $\int_{-\infty}^{L(x'-x)}\frac{\sin(x'')}{x'}\,dx''$ is clearly uniformly bounded.  Then, we have ... continued

Comment: ... continued  $$\begin{align}
\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') \frac{\sin(L(x'-x))}{x'-x}\,dx'&=-\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x') \int_{-\infty}^{L(x'-x)}\frac{\sin(x'')}{x'}\,dx''\,dx'\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x')\lim_{L\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{L(x'-x)}\frac{\sin(x'')}{x'}\,dx''\,dx'\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x') \pi H(x'-x)\,dx'\\\\
&=-\int_{x}^\infty f'(x')\,dx'\\\\
&=f(x)
\end{align}$$